# Xcode indexing takes ages and uses gigabytes of memory

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have a small project that takes ages to get indexed and uses ridiculous amounts of memory while indexing. In the screenshot you can see two Swift processes using 160+ GB of memory. I have this problem only in one project. btw the project uses CocoaPods.

Now if I keep an eye on the Activity monitor and keep kill the processes in time (before they take up too much memory to freeze the Mac), eventually the project is indexed and I can work on it.

What could be the cause of this memory behavior and how can I prevent it?

[Xcode Version 11.2.1 (11B500) on Catalina 10.15.1 (19B88), CocoaPods 1.8.4]

P.S. Doing the usual clean and delete derived data doesn't help at all.

[image: ridiculous]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it !!

I needed to remove `use_frameworks!` from my Podfile (make sure you use cocoapods > 1.5.0) and add

```
install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true
```

Source: https://www.ralfebert.de/ios/blog/cocoapods-clean-input-output-files/

Comment: Unfortunately didn't help :( Are you using SwiftUI or UIKit? I'm using SwiftUI...

Answer (score 2):

I have pretty similar issue. After deleting up to 20+ swift files from project, the bug is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

**Xcode 11.5 and building project in SwiftUI**

Seems like it could be an Xcode bug, basically building/ indexing gets stuck on a particular file and memory gets eaten up.

***Option 1***

If you are in the project and it gets stuck building go to the `Report Navigator` select the build that is currently running and you can see which file Xcode is currently building. Stop the build and check code in that file, if you spot the error and fix it your build will proceed.

***Option 2***

If Xcode gets stuck on launch so it starts indexing the moment you open the project:
Open up Activity Monitor and Force quit the swift process as it builds up. You need to keep quitting the process until indexing perceives itself to be complete. You'll know when Xcode has stopped indexing when the `indexing` label in Xcode disappears. Once you are in your project and memory is not being eaten up, refer to Option 1 above to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue, not sure, but might due to not-rounded height

```html
Button(action: {
                                                self.isSecure = !self.isSecure
                                            }, label: {
                                                Image("hide")
                                                    .resizable()
                                                    .frame(width: 22, height: 15, alignment: .center)
                                                //height: 15.4 cause problem
                                            })
                                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 18, leading: 0, bottom: 16.6, trailing: 13))
```

I changed the Image height from 15.4 to 15 then the swift-frontend(s) don't show up anymore.